# Model Yaml not found within Scrapy project

Tags: python, module, scrapy

I am trying to load the module yaml into a Scrapy scraper, but scrapy keeps telling me that the module is not installed, but it is and works within a another python project.
Within crawler file:

```
import yaml
```

Run crawler:

```
scrapy crawl test

File "/Users/myname/crawler/test.py", line 32, in <module>
import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Trying to install:

```
% pip3 install pyyaml   
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in 
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.3.1)
```

Yaml works within another project, what could be the reason it does  not run within scrapy?

Comment: Are they installed in the same environment?

Comment: I asume so, both commands have been executed within the same shell.

Comment: Please try to open .bash_profile and add `export PYTHONPATH = 'the path to pyyaml'`, then restart the terminal and see if it works.